# Manhwa where the main character is isekaied to a medieval village where everyone is demi-human

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I'm looking for a manhwa where the main characters is teleported or isekaied to a medieval village where everyone is demi-human and the village shaman tells him to save the village. He gets a waifu too; she is a cat or tiger-woman.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. When did you read this and do you recall roughly how many chapters there were? Also, what did the village need to be saved from?

Comment: Was he the only human in that world? Or just the only one in that village?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible you might be looking for *[Saikyou no Shuzoku ga Ningen datta Ken](https://myanimelist.net/manga/115156/Saikyou_no_Shuzoku_ga_Ningen_Datta_Ken)*.

[image: Front cover of Saikyou no Shuzoku ga Ningen datta Ken]

> Having been forced to lead a life full of deception, corporate employee Youji Amezaki has become completely fed up with his work. However, things take a sudden turn when he finds himself transported to a magical world, where humans are considered the strongest beings and even worshipped as gods by many. Despite the dwindling existence of humans in the realm, the populace continues to search for human relics and their immense power, making Youji's appearance a drastic surprise.
>
> After being rescued by Youji and witnessing his remarkable strength, an elf girl named Ria wishes to help him conceal his identity. With the assistance of his newfound companion, Youji embarks on a quest to shelter himself from potential enemies—although the arrival of new, eccentric allies and Ria herself may prove to be distracting.

While Ria is the primary love interest, he [apparently builds up a harem that includes](https://myanimelist.net/reviews.php?id=483036) "slime that turns cute girl, bear ear girl, main girls’s lesbian friend, vampire, “enermy” general, golem girls", which might include a catgirl.